# X won't start after Ignoring BGRT

Tags: fedora, gui, gdm

I have a Toshiba Satellite laptop running Fedora 20 and after a restart the laptop got stuck after this message:

```
Ignoring BGRT invalid status 0 (expected 1)
```

The starting process runs properly until the Fedora logo finishes to fill up. Then the screen flashes about 6 times and it stops. On the top of the screen I see the above message in yellow and then a few lines (0 to 4) of other services that have started successfully.  This is where the GUI stops completely.  If I go to another TTY I can log in properly and all services are running correctly.
The last line of `dmesg` is this:

```
Adjusting hpet more than 11%
```

If I restart the GDM service the system behaves the same way, flashes the screen about 4 to 6 times and nothing else happens.

I'm not sure what changed recently on this system that could have caused this. And I have no idea what exactly is causing this freeze.

### EDIT

Here's the [Xorg.0.log](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/c783ba17424dcf123fa9/raw/d4dde89f07d914a55ee4edfcaa3b2a12c4fdf2f5/Xorg.0.log) file.

Comment: Can you post the contents of Xorg.0.log?

Comment: @amphetamachine the log file is too large. Is there any particular part I should look for or post?

Comment: Use Gist to post the large file.

Comment: @amphetamachine Thank you. I updated the question with the log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by installing Fedora 22. Not the route I wanted, but since the issue was taking too long to fix and I couldn't find anything to point me in the right direction I had to choose the reinstallation.